# Changing cite color in elsarticle

Tags: citing, elsarticle

I like using elsarticle in writing a paper and I like cite color of the Elsevier published journals as shown below.[image]

However, I cannot change the citecolor by using the following command in latex:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=<my_color>, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

In addition, I also don't know what color it is in the above picture.

Please anyone advise how to do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` followed by `\hypersetup{citecolor=Indigo}`? (`DarkBlue` and `NavyBlue` may also be of interest to you.) Pages 38 and 39 of the user guide of the [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/) package list the colors made available with the `dvipsnames` and `svgnames` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the color at begin document, otherwise `elsarticle` chooses its own.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{GBU,
  author={Eastwood, Clint and Van Cleef, Lee and Wallach, Eli},
  title={How to find a tomb with a treasure},
  journal={J. Treasure Searching},
  year=1966,
}
@article{SLIH,
  author={Curtis, Tony and Lemmon, Jack},
  title={How to play bass and saxophone},
  journal={J. Chicago Mafia},
  year=1959,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\end{frontmatter}

We cite \citet{GBU} \citep{SLIH}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]